# Typings for React.createElement are invalid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

How do you use React.createElement with TypeScript ?

```js
import React from "react";


type Props = {
  label: string;
};

const Three: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return <div>{props.label}</div>;
};

/**
 * Three component expects `label` prop
 * But here it is `undefined` - props argument should be second argument
 * Such behaviour leads to error in runtime
 */
const MainButton = (prop: Props) => React.createElement(Three);

export default MainButton
```

[Demo1](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shape-gmzyg?file=/src/App.tsx)
[Demo2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG9y44AbFACMk-AFxwWMKMAB2AcwoBfCuTQRZUuABUAFkSQTk6GADoAYgGEAPEwisAfBzgAKMMxYS7rAJQcnPHxEMACuULJw1gAmwABuDlzu9iymgiL8StYA9DHxyqrqmvAAsihyAEIhMDAazm7MXh5%207E7GGKZoRCgwSACi-EggSLIwLnoGPqpIAB6QsHBRSJgoIfwlZbKV1RoUQA)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
```

This is my workaround. Here I made `props` required argument, because [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L261) they are optional, even if component has properties.

```js
const createElement = <T,>(Comp: FC<T>, props: T) => React.createElement(Comp, props);
```

Am I missing something?
I understand that TS does not complain about missing props because they are optional.
How do you resolve such kind of issue?

I wanted to create an issue on Github, but decided to go here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass props on to the child element:

```
const MainButton = (prop: Props) => React.createElement(Three, props);
```

Or:

```
const MainButton = (prop: Props) => React.createElement(Three, {label: props.label});
```

Or even better yet, just use `Three` as the default export. No need to create a function just to instantiate the element.

Comment: Thanks, did not think in that way ))